# Combining two csv's cuts of some rows

Tags: python, csv

Using python, i have some code which takes the columns of two csv files and combines them into one file. So for example, if my first csv has two columns "column A - Column B" and my second csv has the columns "column C - column D" the resulting file has the columns "column A - column B - column C - column D" with the data in the rows below the headers copied over appropriately.

My problem is that my each of my files have 10000 rows, but the resulting combined file has only 9960 rows, as if the last 40 rows didn't exist in the first place. I can't figure out what could possible be causing this since the code i'm using is very simple.

Below is my code:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open(message_csv, 'r'))
reader1 = csv.reader(open(extra_content, 'r'))
writer = csv.writer(open(content_stitched, 'w'))
for row in reader:
    row1 = next(reader1)
    writer.writerow(row + row1)
```

Comment: are you sure both `csv`s have `10000` rows?

Comment: yes, i've checked using both excel and using code to count the rows, they definitely both have 10,000 rows

Comment: Where is the data? Please see: [mcve].

Comment: Can you confirm what the output of the `pandas.concat` method shows, regarding the row count issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the pandas concat method.

```
import pandas as pd

message = pd.read_csv(message_csv)
extra = pd.read_csv(extra_content)

df = pd.concat([message, extra], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas since it's the right tool for the operation.

```
import pandas as pd 
a = pd.read_csv("file1.csv") 
b = pd.read_csv("file2.csv") 
b = b.dropna(axis=1) 
merged = a.merge(b)
merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False,headers=True)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work, the result is so jumbled i can't really describe what exactly is wrong with it but i think this answer needs some tweaking.